# Saving a visualforce page embedded in Page Layout of Account object redirects abnormally

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, commandbutton, pagereference

I have a VisualForce page inline1 embedded in **Account** page layout. While hitting the save button in the visualforce page it redirects to some other url  :  https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/inline1?id=0019000000BqDd1&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1. But I want this to be in the same account detail page[without refreshing the parent page of course], only to reflect the saved visualforce page. Here is the code :

`public PageReference Save(){ 
  Update lstAcct;
  return null;
 }`

Comment: Your question is broken. Please update it.

Comment: updated the question @ Vignex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid page getting redirected to different URL, **you should not  return PageReference** as the return value for `Save()` method. Instead replace **Pagereference** with **void** and **RERENDER the section** of the page that you tried to save through **rerender attribute of apex:commandButton** from the Inline Visualforce page.

(i.e) Updated code should be

```
public void Save(){
 Update lstAcct;
}
```

Comment: tried this, but its not working....can u please help me get rid of this part in url core.apexpages.devmode.url=1?

Comment: core.apexpages.devmode.url=1- This is not related to your scenario. This is because you've enabled developer mode in your user record. For your scenario, you need not construct any URLs. For more details, I can suggest only after seeing your complete code of your Page and Class

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the devmode on your user profile, Give a shot like this go to User info and uncheck the Devmode and then try. even though it gives error.

in your custom method frame the url where it needs to land.